# AKS Nodepool Upgrade Failed with Azure Activity Log "Operation timeout, please retry."

Tags: azure-aks, azure-container-service

I am attempting to upgrade AKS Kubernetes version from 1.15.3 to 1.15.7. I have successfully upgraded the Control Plane and a nodepool, however the second nodepool isn't upgrading. I've used `az aks nodepool list` and can see `"provisioningState": "Failed"`. The Azure Activity Log shows `Operation timeout, please retry.` as the cause.

1. What could be causing the failure?
2. Are there any logs in Log Analytics to see the cause of the failure?

Comment: can you just retry? sometimes these operations timeout, its pretty expected. you might want to look at the activity logs in the resource group and see if there are any failures

Comment: Just retrying now although the upgrade process has been going for a few hours now and no particular changes to nodes yet. Will report back. Nothing in Activity Logs other than the ```Operation timeout, please retry```

Comment: Failed again on second retry.